# Tweepy installation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I tried to install tweepy by using different methods such as

- pip install tweepy
- sudo pip install tweepy

Lastly, i downloaded zip package from the github and used the command to install:

```
python setup.py install
```

Apparently, installation was completed successfully, however when i run a simple program which contains only one line such as `import tweepy`, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "tweepytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/api.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .packages.ssl_match_hostname import CertificateError
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import ssl_match_hostname
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ssl import CertificateError, match_hostname
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 90, in <module>
    import textwrap
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TextWrapper:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 82, in TextWrapper
    whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(_whitespace, ' ' * len(_whitespace))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

Comment: What OS (Linux, *BSD, OS X?) and what version of python are you using? `sudo pip3 install tweepy` is working fine for me on LMDE Betsy.

Comment: @FredBarclay I have OS X (10.11) and my python version is 2.7.9

Comment: One more question: You're not using `-pip install tweepy` or `-sudo pip install tweepy` (with the dash) are you?  It might also be enlightening to see the output of `python --version` to check that `python setup.py install` used the correct python version.

Comment: @FredBarclay i tried using both methods but none of them worked :(

Comment: No--I'm asking if you used a dash in front of the commands. You know, like `-pip install tweepy` instead of `pip install tweepy` :)

Comment: @FredBarclay i didn't use dashed line with either of them

Comment: Sounds good. The latest edit to the post reflects that. :)

Comment: You are running code written for Python 3, with Python 2. This won't work. maketrans is a classmethod on the bytes built-in type, but only in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
pip3 install tweepy
```

or...

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying. I assume you are using python3. You can have a work-around to make this work by replacing this File
File 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py on line 82`

From

```
whitespace_trans = string.maketrans(
```

to

```
whitespace_trans = str.maketrans(
```

This would make the code compile for python3 docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is another installation option you could try that clones a repo from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
pip install .
```